# Are SQL Server Agent Job Execution History Logs Saved To Disk?

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

What is the default windows server **directory** where the SQL Server Agent 2012 **Job** log files are stored? I would like to transfer the raw log files to a group server so that an external support team can verify that the job executed without necessarily connecting to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there *is* a normal directory for job logs.  Generally, they live in the `msdb` catalog.  When you view a job's history through the GUI, you're effectively looking at something along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT  TOP 1000 *
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sjs
    ON  sj.job_id = sjs.job_id;
```

That said, you should be able to tailor an export of this information to your liking and have your remote support work with that output.

Comment: Thanks Avarkx. Was hoping to source the information without touching the agent job but I guess my choices are limited.